# Sending thousands of fetch requests crashes the browser. Out of memory

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, fetch-api

I was tasked with transferring a large portion of data using javascript and an API from one database to another.  Yes I understand that there are better ways of accomplishing this task, but I was asked to try this method.

I wrote some javascript that makes a GET call to an api that returns an array of data, which I then turnaround and make calls to another api to send this data as individual POST requests.

What I have written so far seems to works fairly well, and I have been able to send over 50k individual POST requests without any errors.  But I am having trouble when the number of POST requests increases past around 100k.  I end up running out of memory and the browser crashes.

From what I understand so far about promises, is that there may be an issue where promises (or something else?) are still kept in heap memory after they are resolved, which results in running out of memory after too many requests.

I've tried 3 different methods to get all the records to POST successfully after searching for the past couple days.  This has included using Bluebirds Promise.map, as well as breaking up the array into chunks first before sending them as POST requests.  Each method seems to work up until it has processed about 100k records before it crashes.

```
async function amGetRequest(controllerName) {

    try{
    const amURL = "http://localhost:8081/api/" + controllerName;

    const amResponse = await fetch(amURL, {
        "method": "GET",
    });

    return await amResponse.json();

    } catch (err) {
        closeModal()
        console.error(err)
    }
};


async function brmPostRequest(controllerName, body) {

    const brmURL = urlBuilderBRM(controllerName);
    const headers = headerBuilderBRM();

    try {
        await fetch(brmURL, {
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": headers,
            "body": JSON.stringify(body)
        });
    }
    catch(error) {
        closeModal()
        console.error(error);
    };
};


//V1.0 Send one by one and resolve all promises at the end.

const amResult = await amGetRequest(controllerName); //(returns an array of ~245,000 records)

let promiseArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < amResult.length; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(await brmPostRequest(controllerName, amResult[i]));
};

const postResults = await Promise.all(promiseArray);



//V2.0 Use bluebirds Promise.map with concurrency set to 100

const amResult = await amGetRequest(controllerName); //(returns an array of ~245,000 records)

const postResults = Promise.map(amResult, async data => {
    await brmPostRequest(controllerName, data);
    return Promise.resolve();
}, {concurrency: 100});



//V3.0 Chunk array into max 1000 records and resolve 1000 promises before looping to the next 1000 records

const amResult = await amGetRequest(controllerName); //(returns an array of ~245,000 records)

const numPasses = Math.ceil(amResult.length / 1000);

for (let i=0; i <= numPasses; i++) {
    let subset = amResult.splice(0,1000);
    let promises = subset.map(async (record) => {
        await brmPostRequest(controllerName, record);
    });

    await Promise.all(promises);

    subset.length = 0; //clear out temp array before looping again
};
```

Is there something that I am missing about getting these promises cleared out of memory after they have been resolved?

Or perhaps a better method of accomplishing this task?

Edit: Disclaimer - I'm still fairly new to JS and still learning.

Comment: What are you really interested in, whatever `brmPostRequest()` delivers, or its side effects?

Comment: Did you try increasing the browser memory? https://www.replicon.com/customer-zone2/kb-4928/

Comment: Does the Bluebird `.map()` option with `concurrency: 100` work just fine?  Or are you saying that has problems too?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: brmPostRequest() simply forms up and sends out a POST request to write a row to a database.  I'm not interested in what it returns.

Comment: @MohanRamalingam I will look into this.  I wasn't aware you could do that.  Thank you.

Comment: @jfriend00 the Bluebird option fails after 100k requests as well.  None of the above options works past around 100k requests

Comment: What are you doing with the results?  What are you accumulating/retaining for 100,000 requests?  If you include more code so we can see what is and isn't be kept alive and away from garbage collection, we'd have a better idea why memory consumption gets so large.  That question will have to do with what you are keeping in scope or purposely in memory and what is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't need to do anything with the results.  The only thing I'm trying to accomplish with this is to pass data between 2 databases using an API.  I first make a fetch request to the origin database, in this case I make a fetch request to the origin db that returns an array containing approx 245k records.  Then I need to individually send each record to the target database.  I added a bit more code to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

*"Well-l-l-l ... you're gonna need to put a **throttle** on this thing!"*

Without (pardon me ...) attempting to dive too deeply into your code, "no matter how many records you need to transfer, you need to control the number of requests that the browser attempts to do *at any one time."*

What's probably happening right now is that you're stacking up hundreds or thousands of "promised" requests in local memory – but, how many requests can the browser actually *transmit* at once?  That should govern the number of requests that the browser actually attempts to do.  As each reply is returned, your software then decides whether to start another request and if so for which record.

Conceptually, you have so-many "worker bees," according to the number of actual network requests your browser can simultaneously do.  Your software never attempts to launch more simultaneous requests than that:  it simply launches one new request as each one request is completed.  Each request, upon completion, triggers code that decides to launch the next one.

So – *you never are* "sending thousands of fetch requests."  You're probably sending only a handful at a time, even though, in this you-controlled manner, "thousands of requests do eventually get sent."

Comment: So when I tried V3.0 in my question above, chunking the array into 1000 records before sending, I could watch the progress in the "Network" tab in Chrome's DevTools and I could see 1000 requests get made with a pending status, then after a few seconds, they all resolve to HTTP status 200 indicating they were processed successfully.  And I can query the database they were getting written to and watch the database fill up with each 1000 record chunk.  I think my issue is that after they are processed, something is being retained in the browser memory and isn't getting garbage collected properly.

Comment: It is currently 6 requests at a time with chrome. Unless you QUIC or something.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not intereted in the values delivered by `brmPostRequest()`, there's no point mapping the original array; neither the promises nor the results need to be acumulated.

Not doing so will save memory and *may* allow progress beyond the 100k sticking point.

```
async function foo() {
    const amResult = await amGetRequest(controllerName);
    let counts = { 'successes': 0, 'errors': 0 };
    for (let i = 0; i < amResult.length; i++) {
        try {
            await brmPostRequest(controllerName, amResult[i]);
            counts.successes += 1;
        } catch(err) {
            counts.errors += 1;
        }
    };
    const console.log(counts);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tested this method and I can see the memory usage steadily climbing up in the Task Manager.  I didn't wait for it to complete to see if it would crash again but I watched the Task Manager for about 10 minutes while this ran and the memory just kept increasing incrementally.  So I am going to assume that I am still having the same issue and it will eventually crash again.  I have added the code for the brmPostRequest() function in my original comment in case there may be issues there.  And I appreciate your help.

Comment: Next thing to try is recursion.

Comment: I've spent the last few days reading up about how to do this using recursion and I'm afraid I may be to green to JS to understand how something like that would work.  Would you be willing to explain please?

Comment: @skyliner33v, yes but I'm away from home right now. I'll see what I can do when I get back. Meanwhile maybe someone else will be able to show you. It's not difficult.