# How Can I Unit Test DDOS Attack on a NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, ddos

i would like to understand DOS (denial-of-service) attacks better and I would like to know what my options are for learning about it with an example.

i have a basic express server.

```
app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ pong: 'pong', time: new Date().valueOf(), memory: process.memoryUsage()})
})
```

I will separately create some javascript code that with make multiple requests to the server. but I don't know to devise strategies to try and bring down the server (consider that this is all running on localhost)

I want to see what the upper limit of making requests is possible when locally testing this. i am experiencing what is described here: [Sending thousands of fetch requests crashes the browser. Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700505/sending-thousands-of-fetch-requests-crashes-the-browser-out-of-memory)

... the suggestions on that thread are more along the lines of "browser running out of memory" and that I should "throttle requests".... but I am actively trying to max out the requests the browser can make without crashing. so far my observations are that the server does not have any difficulty. (so maybe I should also make requests from my phone and tablet?)

the code have run on the browser isn't much more than:

```
    const makeRequestAndAlogTime = () => {
    const startTime = new Date().valueOf();
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/ping')
      .then(async (response) => {
        const { time, memory } = await response.json();
        console.log({
          startTime: 0,
          processTime: time - startTime,
          endTime: new Date().valueOf() - startTime,
          serverMemory: memory,
          browserMemory: performance['memory']
        })
      })
  }

    for(let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      makeRequestAndAlogTime()
    }
```

but depending on what value I put in for the number of times to go through the `for` loop, performance is slower and eventually crashes (as expected)... but I want to know if there is a way I could automate determining the upper limit of requests that I can make on my browsers?

Comment: Hi, take a look at JMeter.  It's open source and is used to load test websites/webapps.  You have a lot control with JMeter in that you create thread groups, and for each thread group you can spawn a number of virtual users, each placing requests against the app under test.

Comment: I use JMeter to measure performance of an app without load and under various levels of load.  This includes a steady amount of load (soak test) and also under what strain does a site/webapp become unstable and then topple over.

Comment: the JMeter tool looks nice. is there a way to incorporate it into unit test to run on CI/CD with perhaps mock performance limitations? because the result of the server in production is going to be different to when running on localhost.

Comment: I've never tried to implement in a CI/CD pipeline.  You'd have to search elsewhere for that answer.  You can tweak the params and load at a global level (one place).  I can't think of the term, but you define, say, "max users" with some value and can then access that number across any element within JMeter using ${max users}.  This is the approach I use for changing params based on environment.

Comment: I think [Ddosify](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify) is the tool you are looking for. It has json output support for [CI/CD integration](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify#usage-for-cicd-pipelines-json-output)